# F# recursion with boolean value

Tags: recursion, f#, functional-programming

So this is the context. Assuming that I have a function that takes a tuple of 2 experiments and test it against a list of rules. The function should stop whenever the tuple of experiments are correctly verified by a certain rule.

```
type exp = A | B | Mix of exp * exp | Var of string

type sufficency = exp * exp  

type rule = Rule of sufficency * (sufficency list) 


let rec findout rules (exp1, exp2) = // return a boolean value
            match rules with
            | [] -> true
            | thisRule::remaining ->
                match thisRule with
                | (suff, condition) ->
                    match suff with
                    | (fstExp, sndExp) ->
                        let map1 = unify Map.empty exp1 fstExp // I don't mention this function in here, but it is defined in my code
                        let map2 = unify Map.empty exp2 sndExp
                        true
                findout remaining (exp1, exp2)
```

The problem is, I have no idea how this could be done with functional programming like this. With imperative programming, it would be easier to loop through the list of rules, rather using recursion to go over the list.

So what should the function return at each stage of the recursion?

I got the warning with that code above

> warning FS0020: This expression should have type 'unit', but has type
>   'bool'. Use 'ignore' to discard the result of the expression, or 'let'
>   to bind the result to a name.

Comment: Your code for `unify` is missing.  Also, `functional <> recursive`.  Feel free to use `List.tryFind` and friends.

Comment: Hi John, I didn't mention the unify function in my post, but it's defined in my code.

Comment: Instead of multiple single-case match statements, you can deconstruct the entire head of the list at once: `| ((fstExp, sndExp), condition) :: remaining ->`. Also it looks like your case for the empty list should return `false`, otherwise `findout` will always return true.

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is in this part of the code

```
            match thisRule with
            | (suff, condition) ->
                match suff with
                | (fstExp, sndExp) ->
                    let map1 = unify Map.empty exp1 fstExp // I don't mention this function in here, but it is defined in my code
                    let map2 = unify Map.empty exp2 sndExp
                    true
            findout remaining (exp1, exp2)
```

The first `match` returns true so you get a warning.  You probably wanted

```
            match thisRule with
            | (suff, condition) ->
                match suff with
                | (fstExp, sndExp) ->
                    let map1 = unify Map.empty exp1 fstExp // I don't mention this function in here, but it is defined in my code
                    let map2 = unify Map.empty exp2 sndExp
                    true && findout remaining (exp1, exp2)
```

Where you carry the `true` through the calculation.  However, this would probably all be simpler if you used the various `List.*` functions.